# InternetReadFile's output to string gives a "ÌÌÌÌÌÌ" sequence in C

Tags: c, wininet

I am trying to read the text content of a HTTP Post Response body using InternetReadFile. However, all it contains is a string of "Ì" (-52 when converted to int).

Could this be encoding related? Is it that what is being returned is not a string at all?

Am I missing a step required to read the output?

Please note that I know for a fact that this message body contains plain text (based on logs).

Here is the code:

```
    Ptr = (char *)OutBuffer;

while(TRUE)
{
    // read the server response
    //
    if(!InternetReadFile(RequestHandle,Ptr,Length ,&BytesRead))
    {
        Rc = GetLastError();
        InternetCloseHandle(RequestHandle );
        SetLastError(Rc);
        return(ACE_HTTP_ERROR);
    }

    if(BytesRead == 0) // end of data
        break;

    TotalLength += BytesRead;
    Ptr += BytesRead;

    if(TotalLength >=  *OutBufferLength)
    {
        InternetCloseHandle(RequestHandle );
        SetLastError(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
        *OutBufferLength = TotalLength;
        return(ACE_HTTP_NO_ENOUGH_SPACE);
    }

}


*OutBufferLength =  TotalLength;
```

At this point, `Ptr`, when read as a char array, contains nothing but a sequence of 'Ì'.

Comment: The Ì character is code 0xcc in code page 1252.  A magic number, tells you that you are looking at uninitialized memory.  Too many bugs in this code.  You must pass Length - TotalLength to InternetReadFile() so it cannot write past the end of the buffer.  You are not zero-terminating the string when you exit early with ACE_HTTP_NO_ENOUGH_SPACE.  And the humdinger, Ptr[TotalLength] = '\0' is badly wrong, you already advanced Ptr.  That must be *Ptr = 0.

Comment: Yes, Ptr[TotalLength] = '\0' was removed as soon as I realised my mistake (and it was temporary code only while testing). And since this buffer does not always contain a string (while it does in this specific case), I handled the whole thing quite differently. Hence, the string not always being terminated.

As for passing "Lenght" being a mistake, all examples I could find does that as well, but your comment does make sense.

Anyway, thanks for the comment, very nice analysis of the code.

Comment: Strange, a long while back, way before any comment was posted here,  I had edited the message to indicate that I had realised what was wrong, but the edit was somehow reverted/deleted. I was basically saying, as pointed out by Hans Passant, that what I was doing made no sense, since Ptr was moved past the content I wanted to read.

Comment: Read the comment on the revert. You do not edit the question to add the answer. You post the answer as an answer.

Comment: My bad, thanks for the explanation. For my defense, I've seen plenty of people getting away with it, but not me :).